# Open SearchView without gaining focus

Tags: android, focus, searchview

I have seen a lot of posts to perform the contrary but here is what I want to achieve. After the user has performed a search through the SearchView, I would like it to stay open but without it being focused or the keyboard being visible.

If it is unclear, just have a look at how search behaves on the Play Store app.

I have tried to give focus to an other View on the screen, to call clearFocus() or setFocusable(false) on the SearchView but nothing works.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. I finally nailed it.

Best way to do it is to override onStartActvityForResult and to manually close the keyboard. This way, you can handle yourself the search and nothing comes to disturb the SearchView which remains in the required state.